# ¿Qué tipo de palabras son los números cuando se refieren a días?

Tags: gramática, morfología

Por ejemplo: el día 16 de Mayo. Ahí no se si es un determinante que acompaña a día o un sustantivo q sintácticamente podríamos calificar como aposición.

Answer (score 5):

Según el [DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/cardinales), el nùmero que designa la fecha es un sustantivo cardinal, en aposición al sustantivo "día" si éste está presente (las negritas son mías):

> Cuando el cardinal con valor ordinal se pospone a un sustantivo femenino, es posible la concordancia de género: *la página doscientas, la habitación trescientas doce*; pero **suele ser más frecuente el uso en aposición del sustantivo masculino que corresponde al nombre del número**: *la página doscientos, la habitación trescientos doce*. De manera general y sistemática se emplean siempre los cardinales para expresar orden en la designación de los años: (año) mil novecientos noventa y ocho, (año) dos mil uno, etc.; y de los días del mes: tres de diciembre, cuatro de octubre, etc., aunque para referirse al día uno puede usarse también el ordinal *primero*.

Otro ejemplo de uso del numeral cardinal masculino en aposición a un sustantivo femenino es:

- la semana veintiuno

Como hablante, no me suena gramatical el uso del adjetivo cardinal femenino pospuesto con valor ordinal (ej. "la semana veintiuna" en lugar de "la semana vigésimo primera"), que según el DPD es posible.